# Prestashop 1.6.0 Import CSV file with custom field

Tags: csv, import, product, prestashop-1.6

I would like to add some custom data to Prestashop product, so I created in mysql table "ps_product" a new column called "real_name", varchar (128). Added key to this column.

After this I added this to available fields

`'real_name' => array('label' => $this->l(' Real name')),`

This to default value

`'real_name' => '',`

This to for cycle which goes over lines

```
if (isset($product->real_name))
{
    $product->real_name = $product->real_name;
}
```

And that's all... Problem is, that value is not properly saved to DB, but its given to the last if, because I tried to log the "$product->real_name" as error and it showed me that value ...

Presta in basic gives me a way to create custom attributes, but I don't know, how to import to them from CSV file. It could be a workaround (maybe with using Function field?).

Many thanks for you advises

Comment: Do you have edit the class, the csv import?
Which files had you edited?

Enjoy your code

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I did not ... This adds the field, but I think, we miss here, the part where are saving datas to DB, check Product and DB classes, I am not continuing on this anymore :)